# Why do the images and text in the html page are also displayed on the popup in this code?[ PHTML]

Tags: php, html, css, bootstrap-modal

I have used following css classes to create a popup box for a button click event.

```
<style type="text/css">
.overlay {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7);
  transition: opacity 500ms;
  visibility: hidden;
  opacity: 0;
}
.overlay:target {
  visibility: visible;
  opacity: 10;
}

.popup {
  margin: 70px auto;
  padding: 20px;
  background: #fff;
  border-radius: 5px;
  width: 40%;
  position: relative;
  transition: all 5s ease-in-out;

}

.popup h2 {
  margin-top: 0;
  color: #333;
  font-family: Tahoma, Arial, sans-serif;
}
.popup .close {
  position: absolute;
  top: 20px;
  right: 30px;
  transition: all 200ms;
  font-size: 30px;
  font-weight: bold;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #333;
}
.popup .close:hover {
  color: #06D85F;
}
.popup .content {
  max-height: 30%;
  overflow: auto;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 700px){
  .box{
    width: 70%;
  }
  .popup{
    width: 70%;
  }
}
</style>
```

Popup is working as expected.But when I scroll down on the popup,images and text which are not in the popup area(Which are below the popup) are also displayed as they are on the same level.I have included a screen shot of my problem.Can any one help me in this? Where have I gone wrong?
I have obtained these classes from the Bootsnip site
https://bootsnipp.com/snippets/featured/ecommerce-quick-view-popup-amp-product-row

This is the problematic view
[image]

Comment: Please [create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: You need to show us your HTML and PHP as well. Your CSS only decides the style, not the content.

Comment: @Shote_SL_ its because of z-index property used for layer position based elements. you need to identify the correct parent element or either elements z-index property and readjust to avoid this

Comment: Rest of the page is just pure html.So I think the error is due to this css classes

Comment: Do you have url pointing to issue?

Comment: Try to give the popup a high `z-index`. See [CSS z-index property](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_pos_z-index.asp) for more informations.

Comment: @yjs http://bvbellpm.com/newtrades/customer/account/

Comment: @yjs log into the site as sadeeenadeee@gmail.com passowrd is admin1 then go to this link  bvbellpm.com/newtrades/customer/account and there click on the track button.

Comment: @yjs Login page  http://bvbellpm.com/newtrades/newlogin/

Comment: @Patrick Mlr I will try it

Comment: Identify this in css: .overlay:target; and replace with .overlay:target {
    visibility: visible;
    opacity: 10;
    z-index: 999;
} Hope that works

Comment: Add `z-index: 1;` to `.overlay`. This should do it.

Comment: @yjs you are a life saviour.It fix the issue.Thanks dude

Comment: @Patric Mlr Thanks.Highly appreciate your support

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just add `z-index: 1` to `.overlay`. This should fix this issue.

See [CSS z-index property](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_pos_z-index.asp) for more informations.

I can't see a different `z-index` value in this case, but If you do, just increase the number of `z-index`.